# biber not working anymore

Tags: biblatex, texlive, biber

I'm currently writing a report in LaTeX and yesterday everything worked fine. Today however, biber isn't working properly (aka at all).
I always get the following error:

> Use of uninitialized value $alias in hash element at C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\par-4f6c65\cache-...\inc\lib/Biber/Section.pm line 469.
>
> Use of uninitialized value $citekey in hash element at C:\yada-yada\inc\lib/Biber/Entries.pm line 57.
>
> Can't call method "datafields" on an undefined value at C:\yada-yada\inc\lib/Biber/Entry.pm line 537.

Until now I deleted the temp-Folder but that changes nothing. I reinstalled Biber as well as biblatex, but nothing changed. I removed MikTex and installed TeXLive 2015, but the error is still not gone.

My library.bib looks like (I mean it's bigger, but the error occurs also with only one entry):

```
% This file was created with JabRef 2.10.
% Encoding: UTF8
@Article{Asahara2015,
  Title                    = {Synthesis of diazabicyclo compounds possessing an $\alpha$-nitrolactam framework},
  Author                   = {Asahara, Haruyasu and Takeda, Shota and Saigo, Kazuhiko and Nishiwaki, Nagatoshi},
  Year                     = {2015},
  Doi                      = {10.1016/j.tetlet.2015.03.100},
  Note                     = {Chalcone synthesis in methanol and water},
  Number                   = {19},
  Pages                    = {2504-2507},
  Url                      = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0040403915005705
http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0040403915005705/1-s2.0-S0040403915005705-main.pdf?_tid=63db364c-4f12-11e5-b336-00000aacb360&acdnat=1440937790_8b4e5199eeccaac75bf2e4028421335f},
  Volume                   = {56},

  Abstract                 = {Diazabicyclo compounds possessing an $\alpha$-nitrolactam framework were directly synthesized upon treatment of $\alpha$-nitro-$\delta$-keto esters with diamines. This reaction proceeds via pseudo-intramolecular process. In this process, the formation of ammonium nitronate is a key step, by which the amino group and the ketone carbonyl group are in close proximity to cause the imine formation efficiently. The following tandem bicyclization constructs 1,7-diaza-3-nitro-2-oxobicyclic systems having two aryl groups at the 4- and 6-positions.},
  Journal                  = {Tetrahedron Letters},
  Keywords                 = {Bicyclic compound
Michael addition
Nitroacetate
Pseudo-intramolecular process},
  Type                     = {Journal Article}
}
```

Hope someone has a solution :)

Comment: Have you tried putting curly brackets around the maths? Also, have you deleted generated files from the working directory? (`.bcf`, `.bbl`, `.aux` etc.) In general, it helps to have a full example matching an actual error so that the line numbers match, although I think in this case they maybe lines in the perl library so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Adding a minimal document, it works fine for me. But I'm not using Windows so Perl is going to be pretty different.

Comment: It happens from time to time that biber cache directorygets corrupted. Delete  the directory: `C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\par-4f6c65` and try start afresh.

Comment: I tried curly brackets, removing the generated files as well as the temporary directory and compiled again. Error is still there.

Comment: Test a small example which doesn't use your bib but uses  biblatex-examples.bib and e.g. cites "shore". Does it break too?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tried this small example:
`\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage[backend=biber, citestyle=numeric-comp, style=chem-angew, sorting=none, mcite=true, subentry]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
yada yada \cite{shore}
\printbibliography
\end{document}`
and that works just fine

Comment: Well then the problem is quite probably in your bib. Comment most of the entries and try again until you find the culprit(s).

Comment: At the moment my .bib file has just the one entry posted in the original question and I get the error. I can't see any errors in the file itself.

Comment: Please note that your `url` field is ill-formed, it should only contain one URL: `url = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0040403915005705}`. In your call to `biblatex` it does make not much sense to first say `citestyle=numeric-comp` and then overwrite it with `style=chem-angew`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with what you have given us so far, is there any chance of providing a bit more information so we can reproduce the issue? You should also try and narrow down the source of the error (some of the fields in your `.bib` are quite verbose).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, I don't know why but for some reason this small snippet in my main document caused the error:

```
\defbibentryset{ref}{ref1,ref2}
```

Comment: You could open a entry at the issue tracker of biber: https://github.com/plk/biber/issues.

Comment: But if you do so, please make sure you have a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) at hand so the issue can be reproduced by the developers.